# SVG line drawing with marker on scroll page

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

trying to draw a growing arrow that will be linked on page scroll. I was able to attach the path to the scroll, but the marker doesn't move with the path.
Please, help how to make the marker move along with the end of the path? Perhaps the end of the arrow through the marker is not the best solution and you know how to do it correctly?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Scroll down this window to draw a triangle.</h2>
<p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>

<svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <marker id="Triangle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="0" refY="10"
            markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3"
            orient="auto">
        <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" fill="context-stroke"/>
    </marker>
</defs>
<path fill="none" marker-end="url(#Triangle)" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" id="triangle" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>



</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

#mySVG {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 210px;
  margin-left:-50px;
}
```

```
// Get the id of the <path> element and the length of <path>
var triangle = document.getElementById("triangle");
var length = triangle.getTotalLength();

// The start position of the drawing
triangle.style.strokeDasharray = length;

// Hide the triangle by offsetting dash. Remove this line to show the triangle before scroll draw
triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

// Find scroll percentage on scroll (using cross-browser properties), and offset dash same amount as percentage scrolled
window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);

  var draw = length * scrollpercent;
  
  // Reverse the drawing (when scrolling upwards)
  triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;
}
```

snippet https://codepen.io/rostislav_blatman/pen/zYLPjQa

find this answer with css animation https://stackoverflow.com/a/75166942/21043600
but this is not the same. In my case need bind on scroll page

Comment: As explained in the previous answer you can't  animate `<marker>` position. You need to calculate the current position and rotation of your triangle on scroll. Have a look at [@ccprog's answer: "SVG Animation: Object along a path on a scroll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188841/svg-animation-object-along-a-path-on-a-scroll#53194605)